# Card reader only works for SD not xD cards

Tags: card-reader

I suspect the answer is "just doesn't work", but it seems odd to me.

My laptop's card reader **works fine for SD cards** but completely ignores **xD** cards: when you plug in an xD card there is nothing in syslog; nothing pops up in nautilus. The same xD card + reader works fine in Windows.

Anyone know whether this is just an unsupported thing? According to [Broadcom](http://www.broadcom.com/products/Ethernet-Controllers-and-Adapters/Enterprise-Client-Controllers/BCM57765) there is a driver for Linux 2.4 and 2.6.

Laptop is Acer Aspire 5750. lshw output here:

```
       *-generic:0
            description: SD Host controller
            product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Memory Card Reader
            vendor: Broadcom Corporation
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
            version: 10
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
            resources: irq:17 memory:c0400000-c040ffff
       *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
            description: System peripheral
            product: Broadcom Corporation
            vendor: Broadcom Corporation
            physical id: 0.2
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.2
            version: 10
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:c0410000-c041ffff
       *-generic:2 UNCLAIMED
            description: System peripheral
            product: Broadcom Corporation
            vendor: Broadcom Corporation
            physical id: 0.3
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.3
            version: 10
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:c0420000-c042ffff
```

Running Precise `Linux 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lshw's website](http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter#Howtointerpretlshwsoutput) says

> a node is marked as UNCLAIMED if no specific support for it has been loaded (or lshw has been unable to identify the driver)

So I conclude that yes, it means the xD part (and presumably the other bits) are unsupported; no (working) kernel driver.